# Exporting a C interface in 64 bit

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I have a dll-ready interface done in XE7 that I want to use in Visual Studio 2013. 
In 32 bits works fine, but in 64 bit I'm getting an exception when trying to call any method of the interface class.

The Embarcadero XE7 project is like this:

```
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual ~Interface() { }

    virtual void Member1() = 0;
};

class Impl : public Interface
{
    public:
        virtual void Member1() { }
};

Impl* Impl::GetInstance()
{
    static Impl instance;
    return &instance;
}

extern "C" Interface* _stdcall _export GetImplementation()
{
    return (Interface*)Impl::GetInstance();
}
```

In Visual Studio I do something like:

```
typedef  Interface* (_stdcall GetImpl) ();

HMODULE hHandle = LoadLibrary(...);
GetImpl *fGetImpl = NULL;

fGetImpl = (GetImpl*)GetProcAddress(hHandle, "GetImplementation");

if (fGetImpl)
{
    Interface *pInterfase = fGetImpl();
    if (pInterfase)
    {
        pInterfase->Member1();
    }
}
```

I have no idea why crashes in 64bit.

Thanks in advance.

Ignasi

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: How did you declare `Interface` in VC++?